# Bing Web Search v7 Results Inconsistencies

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I've been using the Bing Web Search v7 API for roughly about a month now and I'm starting to notice some obscure inconsistencies. Sometimes when I run a query, I get a JSON response with no results. I can then run the same exact query shortly after but this time the JSON returned will contain results. I'm not sure if I'm nearing my TPS limit (which is currently 100/s) but I don't believe I am. I also explicitly check for the URL length to ensure Bing doesn't return an error for a string that's too long. I'm doing queries in the same way that's described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/java). Each query contains a capture group with a set of terms "OR"'d together (which is done following the Bing advanced search guidelines). I had an issue with double spaces causing no results but that has been fixed. Is this possibly a result of the HTTP GET length requirements? Or maybe something wrong with my key? Any help is appreciated and let me know if any more information is required!

Comment: Which queries you are trying?

Comment: @Ronak Given a set of text, we perform NLP to extract nouns and then use Bing's advanced search operators to perform a query on the API. For example, our NLP'd string would be: "female deer". Then we append related terms to that and use quotations to ensure certain words exist in the text. So our whole query string would be: female deer "doe" (woman OR animal). Sometimes those types of queries generate results, other times the query (without alteration) will return a JSON with no results. We've verified the queries produce results by searching the string on Bing. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Could it be syntax errors in your use of the advanced operators? That could very easily cause this behavior and wouldn't present any errors.